# A legality confusion on inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm a newcomer of C++ and my question might be silly:

We have class A, B and C defined as below:

```
class A {
public:
    typedef Resouce Money;
};

class B
   :public A {
};

class C {
public:
    typedef B::Money MyMoney;
};
```

Is this valid? I'm confused because 'Money' is not explicitly defined in class B.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `g++ -c -Wall test.cpp` gives no error.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson you are right. it's valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid, yes.

While `B` does not explicitly define `Money`, it has publically declared (`: public A`) that it has inherited from `A`.  Further, because `A`'s definition of `Money` is public, then `B` will have `Money` as a public member.

Comment: "This is the answer you are looking for" :)

Answer (score 0):

All public and protected members of public (or protected) base classes are accessible members of derived classes. "Members" comprises member variables, member functions and member types, and "types" comprises type aliases and newly defined types.

So indeed the member `A::Money` is also available as `B::Money`.

Comment: Thanks~ Very well summarized:)